# Importing a .txt file into R

Tags: r

I am attempting to import a [.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AwRNIoHD5x9x_H96MU3M8gBZ1M2e25qU/view?usp=sharing) file into R as a data frame. I have tried using read.table as well as read_table and read_delim from the readr package but to no avail. I have tried skipping lines, changing the encoding, and everything I could think of to import the data, but I always get an error message. Does anyone know how to import this file?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: What is the error mesage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless GDrive messes something up, this is bit more interesting as the file  appears to be encoded as `UTF-16LE` and both `read.table()` and `readr` could use some help with that. The file structure is also a bit funky, double-header, trailing `\t` characters and "blank" rows of varying lengths.

First let's see if/how parsers would struggle:

```r
read.table("Bar 64.txt", skip = 4)
#> Warning in readLines(file, skip): line 1 appears to contain an embedded nul
#  ...
#> Warning in read.table("Bar 64.txt", skip = 4): line 1 appears to contain
#> embedded nulls
#  ...
#> Error in read.table("Bar 64.txt", skip = 4): empty beginning of file

readr::read_lines("Bar 64.txt")
#> Error: The size of the connection buffer (131072) was not large enough
#> to fit a complete line:
#>   * Increase it by setting `Sys.setenv("VROOM_CONNECTION_SIZE")`

# at least some progress:
readr::read_file("Bar 64.txt")
#> [1] "t"
```

Now let's try to fix this:

```r
library(readr)
library(stringr)

guess_encoding("Bar 64.txt")
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   encoding   confidence
#>   <chr>           <dbl>
#> 1 UTF-16LE         1   
#> 2 ISO-8859-1       0.29
#> 3 ISO-8859-2       0.21

# set encoding through locale:
read_file("Bar 64.txt", locale = locale(encoding = "UTF-16LE")) |> 
  str_trunc(100) |> 
  str_view()
#> [1] │ t{\t}L{\t}dL{\t}EpsL{\t}Force{\t}
#>     │ s{\t}mm{\t}mm{\t}%{\t}kN{\t}
#>     │ {\t\t\t\t\t}
#>     │ {\t\t}
#>     │ 0.037{\t}24.0060{\t}0.0000{\t}0.000{\t}0.155{\t}
#>     │ 0.103{\t}24.0060{\t}0.0000{\t}...

# progress, but there are still those annoying trailing \t characters that would
# create an empty column and 2nd header row sets all values to <chr>
# would expect read_tsv(..., col_select = 1:5, comment = "s")) to fix both issues, though...
read_tsv("Bar 64.txt", locale = locale(encoding = "UTF-16LE"), 
          comment = "s", col_select = 1:5)
#> Error in x:y: argument of length 0

# but we can clean up those line ourselves too:
read_lines("Bar 64.txt", locale = locale(encoding = "UTF-16LE")) |> 
  str_trim() |>
  str_subset("^s|^$", negate = TRUE) |>
  I() |>
  read_tsv()
#> Rows: 1803 Columns: 5
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: "\t"
#> dbl (5): t, L, dL, EpsL, Force
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
#> # A tibble: 1,803 × 5
#>        t     L      dL   EpsL Force
#>    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 0.037  24.0  0       0     0.155
#>  2 0.103  24.0  0       0     0.142
#>  3 0.637  24.0  0       0     0.185
#>  4 1.09   24.0  0.0001  0.001 0.171
#>  5 1.63   24.0  0       0     0.177
#>  6 2.08   24.0 -0.0002 -0.001 0.153
#>  7 2.62   24.0  0.0004  0.001 0.252
#>  8 3.07   24.0  0.0008  0.003 0.493
#>  9 3.60   24.0  0.0022  0.009 0.773
#> 10 4.06   24.0  0.0032  0.014 1.05 
#> # ℹ 1,793 more rows
```

A sample from the file for reprex:

```
# raw_file_sample <- read_file_raw("Bar 64.txt")[1:220]
raw_file_sample <- as.raw(c(0x74, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x4c, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x64, 
0x00, 0x4c, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x45, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x73, 0x00, 
0x4c, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x46, 0x00, 0x6f, 0x00, 0x72, 0x00, 0x63, 
0x00, 0x65, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x73, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 
0x6d, 0x00, 0x6d, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x6d, 0x00, 0x6d, 0x00, 0x09, 
0x00, 0x25, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x6b, 0x00, 0x4e, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 
0x0a, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x09, 
0x00, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 
0x2e, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x33, 0x00, 0x37, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x32, 
0x00, 0x34, 0x00, 0x2e, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x36, 0x00, 
0x30, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x2e, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 
0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x2e, 0x00, 
0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x2e, 
0x00, 0x31, 0x00, 0x35, 0x00, 0x35, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x0a, 0x00, 
0x30, 0x00, 0x2e, 0x00, 0x31, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x33, 0x00, 0x09, 
0x00, 0x32, 0x00, 0x34, 0x00, 0x2e, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 
0x36, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x2e, 0x00, 0x30, 
0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 
0x2e, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x30, 
0x00, 0x2e, 0x00, 0x31, 0x00, 0x34, 0x00, 0x32, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 
0x0a, 0x00))

write_file(raw_file_sample, "Bar 64.txt")
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

We can read the file twice, once to get the column names, then with skip to get the data rows, and set the names manually:

```
x <- "t L   dL  EpsL    Force   
s   mm  mm  %   kN  


0.037   24.0060 0.0000  0.000   0.155   
0.103   24.0060 0.0000  0.000   0.142   
0.637   24.0060 0.0000  0.000   0.185   
"

#replace text = x with file = "myFileName.txt"
read.table(text = x, skip = 4, 
           col.names = names(read.table(text = x, nrows = 1, header = TRUE)))

#       t      L dL EpsL Force
# 1 0.037 24.006  0    0 0.155
# 2 0.103 24.006  0    0 0.142
# 3 0.637 24.006  0    0 0.185
```